# Challenges for distributed teams across countries

Tags: hiring-process, software-industry, team, telecommute

I was studying a few months ago about distributed teams working in differents time zones and/or countries. In Mike Cohn's book about Scrum, there are a few examples about this kind of situation and how to handle is.

I want to know about its applicability across countries and what challenges are faced considering different laws of hiring. How does that work in practice?

Is it possible for a developer to work from his home in China and telecommute to the USA?

What kind of tools can be used to improve team work and personal contact, even if they are miles away?

I would appreciate to have examples in practice, if they exist.

Answer (score 3):

The two main challenges you will find when working with a globally distributed team are:

1. Time differences. You will not be working with your colleagues at the same time normally (unless they are willing to work in unusual hours) - you *may* have several hours of overlap in times, when you can communicate in real time (phone, skype, IM, for instance). This greatly inhibits quick communication - something that could take 5 minutes on the phone can easily stretch to 2 days of emailing.
2. Language barrier. In particular if your colleagues are in a country where the native language is not yours (or the chosen language for the project). It will take extra time and effort to ensure your communication is clear (avoid abbreviations, slang and culture specific references, for example). There will still be places where meaning will not transfer well (lost in translation...). You will need to use explicit documentation and add detail that you wouldn't normally add when communicating with people in the same office.

There are of course other issues - culture, different holidays and more, but these are secondary to the two major issues I outlined above.

> I want to know about it`s applicability across countries and what challenges are faced considering different laws of hiring. How does that work in practice?

This is difficult to answer, as each country has different employment laws. If you are working with these people as part of the *same* company (i.e. they are employees), you will need to comply with the local laws. Things are easier when working with contractors/freelance workers.

> Is it possible for a developer to work from his home in China and telecommute to the USA?

Well, telecommuting doesn't involve travel. It is simply someone sitting at their (or the office) computer and working on the project. As I outlined in my first point, the real issue here is the time difference.

Don't expect to keep to the same hours around the globe and do expect communication to take a lot longer than you'd expect for a team that is not distributed.

> What kind of tools can be used to improve team work and personal contact, even if they are miles away?

Basically you need to use online systems for collaboration - systems that are available globally.

- Instant messaging for when you are at the same time
- VOIP - something like skype so you can talk
- Online documentation - google docs or a wiki
- Online project management/do to lists basecamp for example

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know about it`s applicability across countries and what
>   challenges are faced  considering different laws of hiring. How does
>   that work in practice?

I think that will probably vary by country and by company, but at least some of the larger companies handle this by having a company/subsidiary registered in each country which they have staff.  Employees are associated with the organization appropriate to their country, and each company/subsidiary operates under the hiring/employment laws associated with its country.

There's a lot of accounting and bookkeeping overhead in that approach, so I'd have to imagine that smaller companies might use a different solution.  I'm not sure what that might be, apart from possibly treating foreign hires as contract workers rather than regular employees.  Then in theory all you'd need is a lawyer competent in the relevant country's contract law to draft up some sort of suitable agreement.

> Is it possible for a developer to work from his home in China and
>   telecommute to the USA?

Yes, although I don't think it's really correct to talk about telecommuting *to* a specific location.  The guy in China could telecommute for the purposes of collaborating with his teammates in the U.S., such as discussing tasks, participating in meetings, etc..

Hopefully you wouldn't expect him to keep U.S. hours and his team(s) would be accommodating enough to schedule their meetings for times that are considered regular working hours in *both* locations.  Sometimes that isn't always possible (time-zone differences can be tricky), but the more accommodating you can make the working environment the more success you'll have with your remote employees.  Nobody wants to have to get up at 2:00 am for a meeting because some manager in an ivory tower decreed "all workers in all countries will keep California time".

> What kind of tools can be used to improve team work and personal
>   contact, even if they are miles away?

There are tons.  At a minimum you will want:

- Text chat (AIM, Skype, MSN, etc.)
- VOIP (again Skype, or Vonage, or any other VOIP solution)
- Video/audio conferencing software (GotoMeeting, WebEx, or something similar)
- Wiki/collaborative document editing (Confluence, Google Docs, MediaWiki, etc.)
- Collaborative project planning/task management/delegation (Jira + Greenhopper works well, or VersionOne, or similar solutions)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It`s more clear now how it can work.

Answer (score 1):

A case study and pretty fundamental introduction on how to handle development like you describe is presented in Martin Fowler's article [Using an Agile Software Process with Offshore Development](http://martinfowler.com/articles/agileOffshore.html).

This article outlines basics and advanced concepts of setting up distributed team communication:

> ```
> Use Continuous Integration to Avoid Integration Headaches
> Have Each Site Send Ambassadors to the Other Sites
> Use Contact Visits to build trust
> Don't Underestimate the Culture Change
> Use wikis to contain common information
> Use Test Scripts to Help Understand the Requirements
> Use Regular Builds to Get Feedback on Functionality
> Use Regular Short Status Meetings
> Use Short Iterations
> Use an Iteration Planning Meeting that's Tailored for Remote Sites
> When Moving a Code Base, Bug Fixing Makes a Good Start
> Separate teams by functionality not activity
> Expect to need more documents.
> Get multiple communication modes working early
> ```

Even for teams where having all of above would be an overkill, mentioned article could be really helpful as a means to have a comprehensive [checklist](http://www.newyorker.com/reporting/2007/12/10/071210fa_fact_gawande?currentPage=all) - so that even skipped items are checked and have clearly documented reasons for rejection - just to make sure nothing important was missed.